# android: how can i access NotificationCompat.Builder using android-support-v4-r6-googlemaps.jar?

Tags: google-maps, android-notifications, android-support-library

In my app I use just one FragmentActivity and implement all other Functions as Fragments. The app should be compatible down to Android 1.6.

Due to the fact that I need a Mapview I implemented the android-support-v4-r6-googlemaps.jar, which works great.

Now I have to implement an alarmsystem with notifications, and then I got stuck. For notifications I seem to need the NotificationCompat.Builder, which is in android-support-v4.jar, but not in my support-library. I can't use both libraries in the same app, but I need at least the Notification package from the android-support-v4.jar. Can I extract this package somehow? Or is there any other solution?

I've been searching for a solution during a lot of hours, but I couldn't find any helpful.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem.

For now I'm just checking android versions, using deprecated approaches for older versions and suppressing the deprecation warnings.

Not a very clean way to handle it, but for now, it'll do.